# Egit: Configure upstream for push and pull

Tags: eclipse, git, push, egit, git-push

I am using Eclipse with Git. I have a local repo, and I want to push that to my private github repo (for safekeeping). I am working alone, so there are no commits from others.

Should I check "Configure upstream for push and pull" in the push dialog?

And if yes, should I check "Merge..." or "rebase"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to check this option necessarily. You can go to Git Repositories view, right click in your githup repo and do push or pull.
Because you are working alone in almost all cases git is going to do fast-foward merge and you don't need to do anything.

Comment: I understand that if I work alone on a project, I can "rebase" without any risc? Instead of "merge"?

Comment: Yes, you can, but don't forget that rebase and merge are different concepts.

Comment: Yes, I know the differente. Thanks